# A PHP Error was encountered error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered error in codeigniter?
i have below error please help.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir(): Invalid path

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 136

Backtrace:

File:/Login.php
Line: 15
Function: __construct

File: /index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: if you are passing any path then that path doesnt exist. try to check the path

Comment: On your session save path try to create a folder some where in application `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'yourfolder/';` with folder permission 0700

Answer (score 2):

Go to application/config/config.php
Find

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

and replace

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```